# Storing inputSteam to database and reading them causes corrupt file

Tags: c#, file-upload, arrays, jquery-file-upload

I am using the C# `HttpPostedFileBase` to save a byte array to my sql server database using this code:

```
private byte[] GetByteArrayFromFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    using (var b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    return b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
}
```

When I read the file I get a corrupted exception with the application I am opening it with like pdf files, excel files. It seems to only work with txt files.

Here is the code I use to retrieve the file:

```
 _response = context.HttpContext.Response;
_response.ContentType = GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(_fileDownloadName));
_response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + _fileDownloadName);
_response.OutputStream.Write(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
_response.Flush();
_stream.Close();
_response.Flush();
_response.End();
```

Comment: Is anything being written to the output stream before you write the file?  If output buffering is enabled you could try _response.Clear() before writing the stream

Comment: I set HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false and I did _response.Clear() before writing the stream and no luck.

Comment: No you want buffer true otherwise it will flush the output before you can clear it.

Comment: Its true by default so i think that wont solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the response output buffering (see [HttpResponse.BufferOutput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.bufferoutput.aspx)):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Also, this article may be useful: [Range-Specific Requests in ASP.NET](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx), see the section "Using the RangeRequestHandlerBase HTTP Handler".